# Geopackage how to view whats in it - Python

Tags: geopandas, matplotlib, google-colab

I'm pretty new when it comes to GIS and such. I am trying to see what data is available inside a geopackage that I downloaded off Natural Earth in Python. How do I do this?

```
#import libraries
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as cl
#create a variable and assign it a string literal containing the relatie path to the geopackage file
gpkg1 = 'demo_data/natural_earth_vector.gpkg'
# Call read file 
countries = gpd.read_file(gpkg, 'country')
```

Comment: https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.plot.html

Comment: What are you trying to do specifically? Show an image of the data? Or just look at it's contents?

Comment: Why not just use a GIS program like qgis? The browser will give a tree view of the layers in the geopkg and the fields within each layer. You can also display the actual data on the map canvas.  If that's too heavy-weight, use an sqlite browser which will show you the tables in the geopkg (which is just a spatialite database) and even let you see the tables themselves.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what data is in your file, you can do this by first doing:

```
print(df.keys())
```

This will tell you what columns of data are in your file. Here you can see what columns you may want to display.

To visualize the data you can use geopandas:

```
gpd.plot(column_name)
plt.show()
```

You can see all the display options here: https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.plot.html